# Place the numbers 1-7 in the squares so that each row and columns adds up to the same total

Tags: puzzle

```
A   F
B D E
C   G
```

A+B+C = B+D+E = F+E+G

Numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: I found 56 solutions.  However, are questions like this allowed on this site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Mathematica software or the Wolfram language.